# Unauthorized Fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm very new to this and have spent most of the day researching this one particular problem. I've tried every suggested solution that I've found on the subject, but none have fixed the issue. I'm trying to push to Heroku, but when I enter:

git push heroku master

I get:

Your key with fingerprint XXX is not authorized to access XXX.

I've tried removing SSH keys, re-adding, and re-pushing, which has not worked. I only have one Heroku account, so I don't think this is a duplicate issue. Getting very frustrated with this issue, can anyone help?

Comment: I assume you have already installed your public SSH key on the remote server, right?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and remove the `heroku.com` line and then try pushing again

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this question, i was also facing the same problem but now it is solved may be it help u as well.. [link][Deploying rails project on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153548/deploying-rails-project-on-heroku)