# Deploying rails project on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, ssh, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working a simple rails project and want to deploy it on heroku just for testing, I am new to heroku and refering the URL `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4`for deploying my project, all things are working fine but when i try to push my project on heroku using this command `git push heroku master` it raises an error saying that

```
!  Your key with fingerprint 83:72:44:8c:67:69:5f:85:34:43:95:2d:a5:6d:54:ac is not authorized to access secret-fjord-7315.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've created the ssh keys using command `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`
Am i doing anything wrong please suggest me what to do? Thanks in advance. I am using rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Please help me guyzz...I need to solve it ASAP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unauthorized Fingerprint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126867/unauthorized-fingerprint)

Comment: Thanks @JohnBeynon for your kind help but can you please tell me where i can find this file ~/.ssh/known_hosts, I've searched it om my mac but can't find it please help me.

Comment: that's where it is, `~/.ssh` is the directory  and known_hosts is the file.

Comment: @JohnBeynon i know ~/.ssh is the directory but i am not able to find that directory on my mac.

Comment: @JohnBeynon I've implemented your suggestion remove the line heroku.com from ~/.ssh/known_hosts but still the things are not working for me, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [heroku accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) it set the ssh keys for you (Using the auto option). Its important what are you doing, so take a look [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys). Hope it helps.

Comment: I used your given refernce but when I run that command heroku account:add personal it gives me an error like that                          !    `account:add` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.  Please suggest what to do now?

Comment: Did you install the plugin? You need to run in your console: heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git

Comment: sorry i didn't install the plugin.. I have installed it and run this command all things are working fine, but still whenever i try to push my project it shows the same error.

Comment: Thanks alot @jorge Najera your suggestion worked...Many thanks..:)